# Get mysql values from cell X by comparing information in cell Y and cell Z?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

The idea: To pull a list of trails in a specific state, or a city in a state.

The database table is wp_postmeta, the columns in the table that we will be using are post_id, meta_key, and meta_value.

post_id can be the same in multiple rows
meta_key must either be "location_state" "location_city" or "trail_type"

So go through each row in the database, look for `post_meta.meta_value = 'Arizona'` and grab the `post_id` from that same row

THEN foreach `post_id` it found in that state look for a value in  `post_meta.meta_key = 'trail_type'` with a matching post_id. This means that the post_id is associated with a trail, and not something else. Return an array of the post_id's which are trails in that state.
to an array called $trails_in_state

Now we have gotten a list of all trails in a state by ID.

I would also like to get all trails in a city of that state into a separate query, so that I can say when the page is hit

```
<?php if( isset($_GET['city']) AND isset($_GET['state']) ) {
   // GET AN ARRAY OF ALL post_id's OF TRAILS IN THAT CITY STATE COMBO
} elseif( isset($_GET['state'])) {
   // GET AN ARRAY OF ALL post_id's OF TRAILS IN THAT STATE
}
```

Here is an image of the table structure http://imgur.com/ijhR1NZ

I'm using wordpress so can't easily use mysqli in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for here. Are you just asking for SQL statements? Are you asking about your table structure?

Comment: I try and provide so much info, that it gets confusing. I'm asking for the PHP code to return the array's I'm after. Right now I have to run multiple for each loops inside of each other, and it's very bad bad bad coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these should get you started.  The first should select you all your post_id's where you're meta_value is equal to an input.  I'm not sure why you need to limit by state or city a broad match should work just fine.  A more specific match to filter on city only would be the 2nd option.

SELECT trail_type FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='Arizona')

and

SELECT trail_type FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id=(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value='Arizona' AND meta_key='location_city' )

Failing that you're either looking at multi selects and sorting or perhaps a UNION query I just can't get my head around that table structure seems counter intuitive to me :(

Comment: What is this? You're first statement is selecting a `post_id` based on a `where post_id = something`. What?

Comment: So there is such a thing as nested MYSQL queries huh? Let me give this a whirl.

Comment: This is my code `$result = ("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = $state )"); 
 $temp = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

The result is an error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Comment: @thatidiotguy What is this? You're first statement is selecting a post_id based on a where post_id = something. What? I know it was an example not a 100% correct answer more of to point him in the direction of sub queries

Comment: @Branndon you forgot the $dataset = mysql_query($result);mysql_fetch_array($dataset);

Comment: Sorry @Dave, my new code `$state = $_GET['tempstate'];
 $result = mysql_query( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = $state )" );
 $temp = mysql_fetch_array($result);` 

still produces the same mysql error

Comment: `$state = $_GET['tempstate']; $result = mysql_query( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$state' )" ) or die(mysql_error()); $temp = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: $state is a string so needs to be enclosed in '

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been trying, different positioning of ' and `

Comment: input strings enclosed in ' table/column names enclosed in ` (though ` is optional in most cases)

Comment: I'm testing the query straight in phpmyadmin on the table, and the error seems to be "Subquery returns more than 1 row" So I'm working on it still to have the nested query only return one result.

Comment: Then you would have to change it to where post_id IN(subquery) rather than post_id=(subquery)

Comment: Wow, I think this will do it! I'll reply back in 5-10 minutes! Thanks @Dave!

Comment: This works! ` $result = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT post_id FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` =  'trail_type' ) AND post_id IN ( SELECT post_id FROM  `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_value` =  '$state') " );`

Comment: you should be able to compond that a little too `$result = mysql_query( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'trail_type' AND meta_value = '$state') " );`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use something like this:

`SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "State" AND meta_value = "mysql_escape_string($state)"`

Comment: Because that doesn't tell me if it's a trail. I could have a hotel listed in that state too.